# Salesforce Duplicate Management

Tags: duplicate-management

I have created some duplicate rules and matching rules to avoid duplicates in the system. This works fine, but I cannot find any documentation on the following:

[image: Duplicate Alert]

What is the difference between `Save (Ignore Alert)` and `Save & New (Ignore Alert)`. Wouldn't the Lead always be a new one anyway?

Comment: Save and new will take you to a page to create another new record. Regular save will take you to the page to view the record that you just created.

Comment: no problem​​​​‍​​​​‍​​​​‍​​​​‍